# Map key to clear mac terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

I have a bad habit of hitting cmd+k in Mac Terminal to clear the screen (and losing my history). I'm wondering if there is a way to map the command-k combo to run /usr/bin/clear when I press it. There are options to map this to a function key, but I'd like to map to the cmd combo if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable command-K by running `defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Clear"="\0";}'` and quitting and reopening Terminal. Then just learn to use control-L instead of command-K.

You can also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to reassign command-K to control-L when Terminal is frontmost. Save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open KeyRemap4MacBook, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.